# Carriage return does not work with ANSI rich text

Tags: r, cat, ansi-escape

I am trying to print text repeatedly on the same line in R (windows). This works if I use the carriage return in the following way:

```
text = c("word 1", "word 2", "word 3")
for (word in text) {
  cat("\rText =",word)
  Sys.sleep(0.4)
}
```

This overrides each line like it should.
However, I would like to print the words in bold and use the ANSI codes `\u001b[1m` and the reset `\u001b[0m` which results in:

```
text = c("word 1", "word 2", "word 3")
for (word in text) {
  cat("\rText =\u001b[1m",word,"\u001b[0m")
  Sys.sleep(0.4)
}
```

This works for the first two prints, but eventually results in the output:

> Text =Text = **word 3**
>   Interestingly enough this does work if ALL output text is in bold font and not only part of it.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not what you're looking for, but maybe it will give you a clue... I've just spent an hour with this puzzle and `\r` and loops of `\b` to backtrack through printed text are all showing bizarre behavior. This worked, but refreshes at the top of the console:

```
text = c("word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4")
for (word in text) {
  cat("\014")
  cat("Text =","\u001b[1m",word)
  Sys.sleep(0.4);
  cat("\u001b[0m");
  flush.console(); 
}
```